# Retrieve data hierarchically in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, hierarchy, subdirectory

I have a structure of 'Folder' entities. Each Folder has a reference to its parent Folder, allowing for a standard tree structure. Each folder can also have a collection of items, let's call them 'Articles'. An article has a title and a body. Given the ID of a root folder, I want to retrieve all the subfolders and their articles. However, I want to only retrieve the article title, not its body. I intend to display the folder structure in a tree view, and I want to retrieve the full article only if the user selects the article in the tree view.

I have set up the relations like so:

```
public class Folder: EntityBase 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentId))]
    public Folder Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class Article : EntityBase
{
   public Guid FolderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FolderId))]
    public Folder Folder { get; set; }

    // this needs to appear in the list
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // potentially large amount of data, retrieve only as necessary
    public string Body { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to tell Entity Framework to recursively go through all the subfolders and their subfolders and so on. Do I have to implement recursion in my code? That seems a bit inefficient. Is there a preferred way to handle this?
Also, how do I retrieve just the title field of my articles, not the whole body?

Comment: LINQ + recursion... again.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that comment? I'm unsure about its intent.

Comment: With a little pun I tried to say that questions about LINQ and recursion are asked time and again. Sorry for letting a bit of cynicism get the better of me.  There's just no magic bullet and there's certainly no one-line statement out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to implement recursion in my code

The alternative recursively loading from the client is load all the Folders with a single query, and let EF fix-up the relationships.  If you don't want to load all the Folders, you can perhaps use a SQL query to just the Folders under a particular Folder (eg using a recursive CTE).

> how do I retrieve just the title field of my articles, not the whole body

EF doesn't support partially loading a single Entity, but you can use "Table Splitting" to split ArticleBody into a separate Entity, even if it is on the same table.

Comment: If you'd said *load all Folders* this wouldn't have been a bad idea. I'm even inclined to think that you actually meant to say that. Of course loading all Articles is a bad idea, which is probably the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Yes should have been load all Folders.  Whichever entity has the relationship.  Point is that apart from Eager Loading, Lazy Loading, and Explicit Loading, there's a little-known fourth way to populate an object graph.  Just load a bunch of entities into a DbContext and EF will connect all the Navigation Properties.